# How to get a clean absolute file path in Java regardless of OS?

Tags: java, path, filepath

Here's the problem. After some concatenations I may happen to have a string like this

```
"C:/shared_resources/samples\\import_packages\\catalog.zip"
```

or even this

```
"C:/shared_resources/samples/subfolder/..\\import_packages\\catalog.zip"
```

I want to have some code that will convert such string into a path with uniform separators.

The first solution that comes to mind is using `new File(srcPath).getCanonicalPath()`, however here's the tricky part. This method relies on the system where the tests are invoked. However I need to pass the string to a remote machine (Selenium Grid node with a browser there), and the systems here and there are Linux and Windows respectively. Therefore trying to do `new File("C:/shared_resources/samples\\import_packages\\catalog.zip").getCanonicalPath()` results in something like `"/home/username/ourproject/C:/shared_resources/samples/import_packages/catalog.zip"`. And using blunt regex replacement doesn't seem a very good solution too.

Is there a way just to prune the path and make delimiters uniform (and possibly resolving `..`'s) without trying to implicitly absolutize it?

Comment: Try something like.. `File f = new File("C:/shared_resources/samples\\import_packages\\catalog.zip");
  System.out.println(f.toURI().toURL());`

Answer (score 32):

Try with this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("myFile.txt");
        Path absolutePath = path.toAbsolutePath();

        System.out.println(absolutePath.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This leaves a `.` in there: `.` gets `D:\git-repositories\winery\winery\.` instead of `D:\git-repositories\winery\winery`. Adding `normalize()` at the end also removes the final `.`.

Comment: toAbsolutePath() does not eliminate redundant relative sections.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
Path absolutePath = path.toAbsolutePath().normalize();
```

... at least to eliminate the redundant relative sections. As the documentation for normalize() mentions, in case that an eliminated node of the path was actually a link, then the resolved file may be different, or no longer be resolvable.

Comment: This helped me to remove the `/../` (Access to upper directory) and get a more "clean" absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`FilenameUtils.normalize()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) from Apache [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

Answer (score -4):

for example here is your path:

```
String jarName = "C:/shared_resources/samples\\import_packages\\catalog.zip"
jarName.replaceAll("/", "\\");
jarName.replaceAll("..", "/");
```